# QProcess does not signal stdout ready

Tags: c++, linux, qt, process, buffer

When I launch xfreerdp process out of shell, it prints INFO messages to stdout and WARN/ERROR messages to stderr, as expected (this is just the default /log-level:info mode).

However, when I launch it via QProcess, the QProcess only signals with `readyReadStandardError()`, i.e. allowing me to read WARN/ERROR messages but never signals with `readyReadStandardOutput()`. Only when the process finishes (I close the xfreerdp window), the signal is emitted by QProcess and all the stdout is read by me (I have no idea, where was it kept all the way long?)

I have found two topics concerning the problem:

- [Qt: How to get live output of a running QProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095885/qt-how-to-get-live-output-of-a-running-qprocess)
- [stdout from QProcess is nowhere near realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223777/stdout-from-qprocess-is-nowhere-near-realtime)

I tried solutions proposed there:

1). I tried to use `QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Unbuffered` as the third argument of `QProcess::start()`. It did not help -- same as it is described by the links.

2). I tried to call `QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()` every 100ms using `QTimer`. However, when I read this way, the output byte array is always empty (until the process is finished). So again, same as told by by the links, it did not help.

When I launch xfreerdp with QProcess with `/log-level:debug` or `/log-level:trace`, the problem does not hold. I get signals of stdout being ready. But there are lots and lots of DEBUG/TRACE messages.

I search for a way to solve the problem. But if I don't find it, I have two options: either to use the default `/log-level:info` option or `/log-level:debug` option. The first one is preferable for me but I am afraid that all that stdout is stuck somewhere and I would get with an overflow of some buffer and the whole thing would crash or it would be like a memory leak (maybe, I will try to explore QProcess source code). The second one is so here, probably, a better option, but the debug mode of xfreerdp is really quite too verbose.

**UPDATE with the minimal reproducible example:**

Alas, one need a vm to connect to.

*If one launches the example (I have checked on Fedora 35 and Fedora 33), one will see that xfreerdp will output the INFO messages only after one will close the xfreerdp window, i.e., only after the process finishes.*

```cpp
//
// main.cpp 
// g++ -o main main.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/qt5 -L/usr/lib64 -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Core
//
#include "QtWidgets/QApplication"
#include "QtCore/QProcess"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    QProcess p;

    QObject::connect(&p, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&](){
        printf("%s", p.readAllStandardOutput().constData());
    });

    p.start("xfreerdp", {"/u:user", "/p:123456", "/v:10.38.31.133", "/cert:tofu"});

    app.exec();

    return 0;
}
```

I am sorry I was mistaken not to post the minimal reproducible example at once. Maybe, I should close the question and create a new once, so that more people could see it?

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it and also tell which version of Qt did you use.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R I have updated my question with the  minimal reproducible example, as you have suggested. Thank you for the piece of advice really.

Answer (score 1):

In your program, `QProcess`  will do like works as entered in the terminal this command :

[image]

For seeing the result better I checked open in Terminal in the Run section of Qt Creator:

[image]

**So I do this in Qt and add some changes to your code:**

```
#include "QtWidgets/QApplication"
#include "QtCore/QProcess"

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication  app { argc, argv };
    QProcess     *p = new QProcess();
    QStringList   pArgs;

    pArgs << "/u:user" << "/p:123456" << "/v:10.38.31.133" << "/cert:tofu";

    p->setProgram(QString("xfreerdp"));
    p->setArguments(pArgs);

    p->start();

    QObject::connect(p, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&]()
    {
// printf("%s", p->readAllStandardOutput().constData());
        qDebug() << p->readAllStandardOutput().constData() << Qt::endl;
    });

    app.exec();

    return 0;
}
```

you should take **Arguments** to QProcess by using `QStringList`.

As I test it takes 15 to 16 seconds delay to show you results but this is my results:

[image]

Comment: I have tried your version, but it did not help. Alas. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @JenyaKh, It has 16s delay to show results and I don't know why.

Comment: Sorry for the delay with the answer. I think this is because you cannot connect to a vm (as the ip does not exist in your network). So xfreerdp is trying to connect and then finally after 16 seconds dies. So after it dies, the process finishes and the stdout INFO messages are finally written to the screen. So this is the same behavior as I observe, just I have the ip in my network and connect to it successfully and have to close the window with the vm's desktop to finish the process and get the stdout INFO messages.