# Is there an stdbuf equivalent for Windows 7 command prompt?

Tags: stdout, stderr, io-redirection

So gnu has stdbuf which allows you to modify buffering of a command's I/O stream.  I need the same functionality for command prompt but I can't seem to find anything about it.

I'm simply trying to output both stdout and stderr of a program, to a logfile, without buffering (or rather, just so that they are in sync and in the same order they would be displayed as in the console).

Did I just miss some obvious command or syntax, or am I just out of luck in windows?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true). I don't have Windows to test on, but my guess is that you would need something like this:

```
.\foo.bat > .\bar.log 2>&1
```

This will default to buffered IO, which is not exactly what you want, but unbuffered output [does not seem to be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385427/disable-buffering-on-redirected-stdout-pipe-win32-api-c).